# Why property of 'color' does not exist on type 'Vehicle' in TypeScriptlang?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was practicing TypeScript between my code editor and typescriptlang.org and in the latter I get an error message that says `Property of 'color' does not exist on type 'Vehicle'` for the following code:

```
class Vehicle {
  // color: string;

  constructor(color: string) {
    this.color = color;
  } 

    protected honk(): void {
    console.log('beep beep!');
  }
}

const vehicle = new Vehicle('orange');
console.log(vehicle.color);

class Car extends Vehicle {
    private drive(): void {
    console.log('chugga chugga');
  }

  startDrivingProcess(): void {
    this.drive();
    this.honk();
  }
}

const car = new Car();
car.startDrivingProcess();
```

That does not seem right, I am defining that property in the `constructor()`. It only seems to work when I uncomment `color: string;`.

It works in VS Code but I get an error in typescriptlang.org, but that should not matter because this is a JavaScript rule. I have two ways to define that color property, one of them being via the `constructor()` function.

```
class Vehicle {
  color: string;

  constructor(color: string) {
    this.color = color;
  } 

    protected honk(): void {
    console.log('beep beep!');
  }
}

// const vehicle = new Vehicle('orange');
// console.log(vehicle.color);

// class Car extends Vehicle {
//  private drive(): void {
//      console.log('chugga chugga');
//   }

//   startDrivingProcess(): void {
//     this.drive();
//     this.honk();
//   }
// }

// const car = new Car();
// car.startDrivingProcess();
```

Comment: "*That does not seem right, I am defining that property in the constructor()*" but you've not declared that your class should actually have such a property. How is TS to know if that's what you actually want? Imagine you actually declared `color: string` as a class property, then in the constructor you did `this.colour = "red"`. Should TS ***not*** tell you that's wrong?

Comment: @VLAZ, okay, that makes sense, I wonder why inside of VS Code, TypeScript did not complain. Regardless, thank you for your answer.

Comment: [It does show an error for me](https://i.imgur.com/XLwi1sm.png). Perhaps you need to configure something in VSCode. I'm not sure I've done anything special to make it recognise TS errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is **statically typed** ... meaning that the compiler must know everything about the code at compile time. Objects / classes cannot dynamically change themselves at runtime.

JavaScript is **dynamically typed** ... meaning that the shape of objects / classes can change at any given moment at runtime.

Here's an example:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}
```

In the above class, you are **dynamically** allocating a field called `name` to the an object of type `Foo`.

If you want typescript to be aware of this a compile time, you need to specify a property.

```js
class Foo {
  readonly name: string // now TS is aware of the field at compile time

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}
```